# Are identical paths with the only difference that one uses query but the other path parameters allowed?

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-2.0

My problem is similar to the one asked in the "Paths that differ only in query parameter names" post. However, I am not interested in identical paths that use different query parameter; instead, my problem is concerning similar paths that use the same parameters but take those parameters as input in a different way, one as query parameters and the other as path parameters.

I tried using creating two different paths in my swagger.json file, one containing them as query parameters and the other as path parameters, but it did not work. Please see below my code:

```
  '''swagger.json 
 { 
  // swagger initialisation
  "paths":{
    "foo_b_ar/{foo}/{bar}":{
      "get":{
        "summary":"foo foo"
        "operationId": "super secret id"
        "produces":[
          "someName/json"
         ],
        "parameters":[ 
        { 
         "name" = "foo",
         "in" = "path",
         "description" = "something",
         "required" = true,
         "type" = "string"
        },
        { 
         "name" = "bar",
         "in" = "path",
         "description" = "something2",
         "required" = true,
         "type" = "string"
        }
        ], 
        "responses":{ 
              // something not relevant
        } } },
    "foo_b_ar":{
      "get":{
       "summary":"foo foo"
       "operationId": "super secret id"
       "produces":[
        "someName/json"
       ],
       "parameters":[ 
        { 
         "name" = "foo",
         "in" = "query",
         "description" = "something",
         "required" = true,
         "type" = "string"
        },
        { 
         "name" = "bar",
         "in" = "query",
         "description" = "something2",
         "required" = true,
         "type" = "string"
        }
       ], 
       "responses":{ 
         // something not relevant
       } } }
     }
```

My question is whether what I am trying to do in the swagger.json file is allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/foo_b_ar` and `/foo_b_ar/{foo}/{bar}` (note the leading `/` - it's required in path names) are different paths.

`/foo_b_ar/smth/other` and `/foo_b_ar/{foo}/{bar}` are also different paths, the former (concrete) definition is supposed to match first if used.

Example of identical paths:

- `/{foo}` and `/{bar}`
- `/foo_b_ar/{foo}` and `/foo_b_ar/{bar}`
- `/foo_b_ar/{foo}/{bar}` and `/foo_b_ar/{param1}/{param2}`
- `/foo_b_ar/{foo}/something` and `/foo_b_ar/{bar}/something`
- `/foo_b_ar/something/{foo}` and `/foo_b_ar/something/{bar}`

That is, identical paths are paths that would be the same if you removed the `{parameters}` from them.

As for why "it did not work", without knowing the details of what exactly did not work and where, it could be because your swagger.json is not valid JSON and also not a valid OpenAPI definition. Please validate it using a JSON validator (e.g. https://jsonlint.com) and in Swagger Editor (https://editor.swagger.io). Some of the errors are:

- Missing commas between object fields in JSON.
- Invalid key/value separators (`=` instead of `:`).
- Missing `/` at the beginning of paths. `"foo_b_ar"` is not a valid path, it must be `"/foo_b_ar"`.
- Duplicate operation IDs: `"operationId": "super secret id"`.